# What's the difference between Python pip's pip.conf and pypirc file?

Tags: python, pip, nexus, pypi

I'm having trouble reaching a nexus server that we're using to store custom python packages. I've been told to change the settings in both my `~/.pypirc` file and the `~/.pip/pip.conf` file.

What's the difference between those two files in how they're used? It seems like the `pip install -r requirements.txt` command refers to the `pip.conf` file, and then the fields within the `pip.conf` file requires looking up the pypirc file?

Example pip.conf file:

```
[global]
index = https://user:password@someurl.com/somerepo/pypi-group/pypi
index-url = index = https://user:password@someurl.com/somerepo/pypi-group/simple
```

Example pypirc file:

```
[distutils]
index-servers =
    pypi
    nexus

[pypi]
repository: https://pypi.org/pypi
username: abc
password: def

[nexus]
repository: https://someurl.com/somerepo/pypi-internal
username: someuser
password: somepassword
```

Also, what's the difference between index and index-url in the pip.conf file?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

`.pypirc` is a file standard used by multiple tools, *but not by `pip`*. For example, the `easy_install` tool [reads that file](https://pythonhosted.org/an_example_pypi_project/setuptools.html#intermezzo-pypirc-file-and-gpg), as does [`twine`](https://github.com/pypa/twine). It contains configuration on how to access specific PyPI index servers *when publishing a package*.

`pip.conf` on the other hand is *only* used by the `pip` tool, and `pip` never publishes packages, it downloads packages from them. As such, it never looks at the `.pypirc` file.

If you are not publishing packages, you don't need a `.pypirc` file. You can't use it to configure index servers for `pip`.

As for the `--index-url` and `--index` switches, these are used for different `pip` commands.

- `--index-url` is a common switch among several pip commands that deal with installing packages (`pip install`, `pip download`, `pip list`, and `pip wheel`), where it is part of a group of switches (together with `--extra-index-url`, `--no-index`, `--find-links` and `--process-dependency-links` and a few deprecated switches) that all together configure how package discovery works. The URL must point to a [PEP 503 Simple Repository API](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0503/) location, the default is `https://pypi.org/simple`.
- `--index` is only used by `pip search`; it only needs this one piece of information. It is named separately because it should point to the public search web interface, not the simple repository! For https://pypi.org, that's `https://pypi.org/pypi`.